# Eloquent Ruby - saving code blocks to execute later example

Tags: ruby, block

In Eloquent Ruby there's a code example I don't understand.

```
class Document
  attr_accessor :save_listener

  # most of the class omitted...

  def on_save( &block )
    @save_listener = block
  end

  def save( path )
    File.open( path, 'w' ) { |f| f.print( @contents ) }
    @save_listener.call( self, path ) if @save_listener
  end
end

# usage
my_doc = Document.new( 'block based example', 'russ', '' )
my_doc.on_save do |doc|
  puts "Hey, I've been saved!"
end
```

Why is it that `@save_listener.call( self, path )` takes TWO arguments? The block that's saved looks like it only has ONE parameter `|doc|`. Is this a typo in the book or is there something here I'm missing?

I even tried typing this code in and executing it and I found I can add as many parameters as I want and there wont be any errors. But I still don't get why there are TWO parameters in this example.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is due to a subtle difference between `Proc` and `Lambda`. When you create a new `Proc` with a block of code, you can pass as many arguments as you'd like to it when you call it. For instance:

```
proc = Proc.new {|a,b| a + b}
proc.arity #=> 2 -- the number of arguments the Proc expects
proc.call(4,8) #=> 12
proc.call(4,8,15,16,23,42) #=> 12
```

It is taking in those arguments but just not assigning them to any of the variables in your block.

However, a `Lambda` cares about the number of arguments.

```
proc = lambda {|a,b| a + b}
proc.arity #=> 2
proc.call(4,8) #=> 12
proc.call(4,8,15,16,23,42) #=> ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (6 for 2)
```

The reason for this is because `Proc.call` assigns the method's arguments similar to parallel assignment of variables.

```
num1, num2 = 1,2 #=> num1 is 1, num2 is 2
num1, num2 = 1  #=> num1 is 1, num2 is nil
num1, num2 = 1,2,3,4,5 #=> num1 is 1, num2 is 2 and the rest are discarded
```

However, `Lambda` does not work like this. `Lambda` acts more like a method call than a variable assignment.

So, if you are worried about only allowing a certain number of arguments, use `Lambda`. However, in this example, since there is a chance you can add a path to the block, a `Proc` is best.

Answer (score 1):

It looks useless in that example, but you can pass as many arguments as you want to the block and they'll get ignored. You can also call it without arguments in this case.